# Beta Distribution Fitting in R -- Various Attempts

Tags: r, distribution, mle, model-fitting

I need to fit a custom probability density (based on the symmetric beta distribution B(shape, shape), where the two parameters shape1 and shape2 are identical) to my data.
The trouble is that I experience some problems also when dealing with the plain vanilla symmetric beta distribution.
Please consider the code at the end of the post.
In the code, dbeta1 is the density of the beta distribution for shape1=shape2=shape.
In the code, dbeta2 is the same quantity written explicitly, without the normalization factor (which should not matter at all if we talk about maximizing a quantity).

I then generate some random numbers according to Beta(0.2, 0.2) and I try to estimate the shape parameter using

1) fitdistr from MASS

2) mle from stats4

Results: generally speaking I have non-sense estimates of the shape parameter when I use dbeta2 instead of dbeta1 and I do not understand why.
On top of that, mle crashes with dbeta2 and often I have numerical problems depending on how I seed the x sequence of random numbers.

I must be misunderstanding something, so any suggestion is appreciated.

```
library(MASS)
library(stats4)

dbeta1 <- function(x, shape, ...)
  dbeta(x, shape, shape, ...)

dbeta2 <- function(x, shape){
  res <- x^(shape-1)*(1-x)^(shape-1)
  return(res)
}

LL1 <- function(shape){
  R <- dbeta1(x, shape)
  res <- -sum(log(R))
  return(res)
}

LL2 <- function(shape){
  R <- dbeta2(x, shape)
  res <- -sum(log(R))
  return(res)
}

set.seed(124)
x <- rbeta(1000, 0.2, 0.2)

fit_dbeta1 <- fitdistr( x , dbeta1, start=list(shape=0.5) ,       method="Brent", lower=c(0), upper=c(1))
print("estimate of shape from fit_dbeta1 is")
print(fit_dbeta1$estimate)

fit_dbeta2 <- fitdistr( x , dbeta2, start=list(shape=0.5) , method="Brent", lower=c(0), upper=c(1))
print("estimate of shape from fit_dbeta2 is")
print(fit_dbeta2$estimate)

fit_LL1 <- mle(LL1, start=list(shape=0.5))
print("estimate of from fit_LL1")
print(summary(fit_LL1))

## this does not work
fit_LL2 <- mle(LL2, start=list(shape=0.5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I understood the problem. Missing out the normalisation factor in dbeta2 was the issue, because that quantity also depends on shape.
If I use

```
dbeta2 <- function(x, shape){


res <- x^(shape-1)*(1-x)^(shape-1)/beta(shape, shape)

return(res)

}
```

then the results are consistent.